# How do you make Minecraft mods?

Tags: minecraft-modding, modding

I want to make my own Minecraft mods and I'm wondering what I need to do to get started. Is there any good software or anything for it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Download [MCP](http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/index.php/Main_Page), aka the Minecraft Coder Pack. This is how all the mods were released, and I've used it a couple of times, albeit for simple mods.

Comment: The MCP link in this post seems to be dead now.

Answer (score 6):

You need a couple of things:

- Basic Java programming skills
- MCP (Minecraft Coder Pack)
- A code decompiler (EditRocket, Eclipse, NetBeans)
- A good idea that nobody has done already (Unless you want to do it for practice)

After you have those, you need to set up MCP. You can find videos on how to do that on youtube. (I don't know if you have Windows XP, Windows 7, Mac) You need to set up the decompiler. (I don't know which one you will get, so I can't help with that) Once all that is done, you can code! Depending on which mod you want to make (Mobs, Items, Blocks), you will need to learn how to do this. I would start with new crafting recipes, like craftable web, or craftable spawners. Once you learn a little about how the minecraft modding works, you can start to make more complex mods. If you need help with learning how to do something for your mod, what I do is look up tutorials on youtube, or look on a search engine. If you need any more info, just comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Use MCP, just like SourceTurtle said. If you need help using it, here are some YouTube tutorials I found:

- [GlennBrannMC](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAN305cIemDN1p2SqYDbks-SJcRunwyJP)
- [x2robbie2x](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB1D8D9B290C09EAB)
- [HDAViiRuS](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1F9E91B6236BE799)
- [sciguy1121](http://www.youtube.com/user/sciguy1121)

Answer (score -2):

go to minecraft forge website download source and run install
(http://www.minecraftforge.net)