# Are there any good guides for making mods for Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-modding, modding

I've been coding in Java for 5 months at work now, and having past experience with programming in other languages, modifying existing code at Uni etc.  I feel like I want to get started on (read: continue learning to program by) modding with minecraft.

I know what I [*need*](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/16583/18913), but not exactly how to do so. I once saw some good guides on the minecraft forum, but they all explained how to write in java, hows different classes in the code work etc. I'm more interested in how you decompile the code, write your own separate from the main 'trunk' of minecraft and then package it to install with a tool like 'Magic Loader'.

My issue with these guides is that they always relied on being in windows, but I'm primarily a linux user, and the guides on the forums only seemed to assume you were on a Windows box.

So is there a good 'walkthrough' for modding for Minecraft? Especially one where it assumes or at least allows for the fact you are in linux?

Comment: Tried [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=minecraft+mod+guide+linux)?

Comment: @Byte56 yes I have done basic research. All of those those results are for *installing* mods, with one or two for something called 'mod maker' which is a gui interface which allows limited mad making, no coding involved. The other search I ran, [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=minecraft+mod+guide+linux) has similar results.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed, but I've just started on this path too. I answered this Q for myself thusly: mod to the popular Forge API, and follow the series of very good tutorials on the Forge wiki.

Answer (score 3):

Check out MCP! That's Minecraft Coder's Pack. It takes care of all the compilation/building etc... You just need to worry about modding :)

Setup tutorials: (one of these should have you covered)
http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/index.php/Using_MCP_video_collection

How to set up with Eclipse (after main setup):
http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/index.php/MCP_Mod_System:_Eclipse_Setup_Tutorial

Some itneresting tutorials:
http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/index.php/Category:Tutorials

EDIT: Fail, you already knew about MCP! oh well, the tutorials still stand :)

Answer (score 2):

If you do have some Java experience you should read the official MinecraftWiki Mods

http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Mods