# How do I decompile Minecraft?

Tags: java, minecraft-modding, modding

I'm trying to get started modding Minecraft. I opened up the `minecraft.jar` file in Eclipse, but it doesn't contain what I expected.

In [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WB4mZ5f42Vg&index=1&list=PL255772B4187BF4B8) the presenter decompiles `minecraft.jar` and finds things like armor and blocks packages, but when I put my `minecraft.jar` file (from `[user]\appdata\roaming\.minecraft`) into Eclipse, I only see Apache and Ydggrassil authentication and such.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question should be closed as an attempt at a breach of copywrite.

Comment: @Wardy: this could also be for modding, which is very common in the Minecraft verse. I don't think it's appropriate for GDSE, though.

Comment: This *topic* is perfectly acceptable here, but I am not really sure this is a good *question* for this site.

Comment: fair enough, someone pointed out that EULA allows this (wierd but cool) :)

Comment: Why is this not a good question for this site?

Comment: @Wardy Just to seal it with a reference: [Here's the EULA](https://account.mojang.com/documents/minecraft_eula). It says "If you've bought the Game, you may play around with it and modify it."

Comment: I found [a similar closed question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16583/how-do-you-make-minecraft-mods). Its answers might be helpful. This question is more specific and clear though.

Answer (score 8):

You can't just open the jar in Eclipse. Even if you have some kind of decompiler-plugin, you will only see obfuscated code.

You will need the [Minecraft Coder Pack](http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/) to decompile *and deobfuscate*  the jar (as well as MCP can anyway) so you can work with the code.

Additionally, if you want do develop Minecraft-Forge mods you should check out [this page](http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Installation/Source).
Forge also requires MCP to decompile the jar, but it's automatically downloaded during installation.

Comment: If I remember correctly, nowadays Minecraft also ships with a dictionary of what got obfuscated to what, officially.